# Myths with people whose eyes can turn yellow?

Tags: myth-identification

Is there anything in any mythology that depicts humans whose eyes can change colour to be yellow? Perhaps to scare spirits or other supernatural beings?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide some info on where this notion arose.  (I can think of at least one referent in modern fantasy literature, for instance.)

Comment: In *The Argonautica*, the descendants of Helios are said to have eyes that "glittered like gold."  But it doesn't indicate there's some special power to them otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

- [Sun WuKong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_King) (aka The Monkey King)

This beloved mythological figure is famous for having golden eyes:

> Eventually, through the teamwork of Taoist and Buddhist forces, including the efforts from some of the greatest deities, and then finally by the Bodhisattva of mercy, Guanyin, Sun Wukong is captured. After several failed attempts at execution, Sun Wukong is locked into Laozi's eight-way trigram Crucible to be distilled into an elixir (so that Laozi could regain his pills of longevity) by samadhi fires.

> After 49 days, however, when the cauldron is opened, the Monkey King jumps out, having survived by hiding in a corner marked by the wind trigram in which there was no fire. Additionally the heat from the samadhi fires reinforces the Monkey King's bodily frame, making him stronger than ever before, and impervious to damage. The heat also gives him a new ability; the Monkey King is now able to recognize evil with huǒyǎn-jīnjīng (火眼金睛) (lit. "golden-gaze fiery-eyes"). Sun Wukong proceeds to destroy the crucible and makes his way to Heaven's main chamber, to confront the Jade Emperor and his senior advisers.

Not specifically the answer you're looking for, but, Sun Wukong can also transform himself into many forms, and ostensibly hide and re-reveal his golden eyes.